# change uitableviewheader height

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a Storyboard with a UITableView. The tableView gets a tableViewHeader like:

```
----------------------
| Button             |
| Label              |
----------------------
```

The button appears only if a condition is met. Also, if the button is clicked the header must be:

```
----------------------
| Label              |
----------------------
```

I tried lots of things, like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 59);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 59);
                             self.viewButton.hidden = YES;
                         }
                     }
     ];
```

This works great if I click the button. But once I scroll the table view up, it bounces at 0 and then offset is lost, my table view looks like:

```
----------------------
|                    |
| Label              |
----------------------
```

I also tried all kinds of views manipulation and tried reset the tableViewHeader, like:

```
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
frame.size.height = 31; 
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:self.viewTitle];
```

Getting the result:

```
----------------------
|                    |
|            Label   |
----------------------
```

I saw something about changing my UITableViewController to a UIViewController and my problems will be resolved by manipulating the view controller frame, but I have like 10 table view and I don't really have time to make all the changes I need.

Please, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a UIViewController with a UITableView inside. My piece of advise here is: forget about the UITableViewController. It is a mess. The solution is:

Button:

```
- (IBAction)synchronizeTouchUpInside:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -59, 320, 367 + 59);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if (1 == 1) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -59, 320, 367 + 59);
    } else {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367);
    }

}
```

Now I just need to rebuild a lot of table view controllers. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 5):

I got similar issue resolved by re-assigning the same object to the table view header:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
```

Note that table header view should already be resized prior to this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is just a copy/paste problem, but I think that when you change the header frame you are missing a step; try with this:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
frame.size.height = 31; 
self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = frame;
```

If you omit the last assignment, you have just created a local `CGRect` and modified its value, not actually changed the header's frame.

Comment: `self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = frame` causes a constraint crash. I tried to alloc a new frame to solve that.

Comment: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint UIView:0x8d77fd0.bottom == UIView:0x8d767e0.bottom. Break on objc_exception_throw.